# UnrecognizedToken Error in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to repeat the example of creating an email with inline images as shown [here](http://winsysadm.net/send-mail-with-inline-embedded-images-with-powershell/), but I encounter an error when using a variable `$SmtpSender` in the `From` element. The code is as follows:

```
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$msg.From = "<a href="$SmtpSender">$SmtpSender</a>"
```

and the error is here:

```
Unrecognized token in source text.
At D:\Testing\Data\Powershell\LoadRunner\LRmain.ps1:82 char:13
+ $msg.From =  <<<< "<a href="$SmtpSender">$SmtpSender</a>"
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken
```

The variable `$SmtpSender` is defined. How to fix this problem?

Comment: $msg.From = "<a href=`"$SmtpSender`">$SmtpSender</a>"  (use back ticks to escape the double quote in your href reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `$msg.From = $SmtpSender` without the html tagging.